# Get a name from other tables when making a sql query, if the id fields are the same

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. FirstTable is like this:

| **id** | **id2** | **id3** | **message** | **info** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | hello! | none |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | hi there | none |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | hi man | none |

SecondTable is:

| **id2** | **name** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | Bob |

ThirdTable is:

| **id3** | **name** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rob |
| 2 | Tom |
| 3 | Joe |

As you can see, in FirstTable always only one of id2 and id3 column's values is not zero. So, I want to get the result as below:

> 1 - Tom - hello!

or

> 2 - Alex - hi there

or

> 3 - Joe - hi man

I cannot use a query like

```
SELECT 
    FirstTable.id AS id, FirstTable.message AS message,   
    FirstTable.info AS info, 
    SecondTable.name AS name1, 
    ThirdTable.name AS name2, 
FROM 
    FirstTable, SecondTable, ThirdTable 
WHERE 
    FirstTable.id = 1 
    AND FirstTable.id2 = SecondTable.id2 
    AND FirstTable.id3 = ThirdTable.id3 
ORDER BY 
    FirstTable.id DESC
```

because I do not have 0 only one of id2/id3 in FirstTable. What is the right query to get something like

> 1 - Tom - hello!

? Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can accoumplish that by using two LEFT JOINs

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`id` int, `id2` int, `id3` int, `message` varchar(8), `info` varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`id`, `id2`, `id3`, `message`, `info`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 0, 2, 'hello!', 'none'),
>     (2, 1, 0, 'hi there', 'none'),
>     (3, 0, 3, 'hi man', 'none')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2
>     (`id2` int, `name` varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table2
>     (`id2`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Alex'),
>     (2, 'Bob')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table3
>     (`id3` int, `name` varchar(3))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table3
>     (`id3`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Rob'),
>     (2, 'Tom'),
>     (3, 'Joe')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.`id`,
> CASE WHEN t1.id2 = 0 THEN t3.`name`
> ELSE t2.`name`END name,
> t1.message
> FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id2=t2.id2 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id3 = t3.id3
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | message 
> -: | :--- | :-------
>  1 | Tom  | hello!  
>  2 | Alex | hi there
>  3 | Joe  | hi man
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94e5dd594097a1778824ea89f1e4afa0)*